# flexbox: No space between two vertical icons

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

Hello guys i've this layout:

[image]

Now this is what i tried:

reset padding and margin, in the `<a href>` and in the `<img src...>`

***HTML container***

```
<div>
    <div className="percentage">
        {percentage}%
        <div className="buttonContainer">
            <HandlePercentageButton add onClick={() => this.handlePercentage('add')} />
                <HandlePercentageButton subtract onClick={() => this.handlePercentage('subtract')} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <span className="labelBudget">Budget allocato</span> 
</div>
```

***HTML handlePercentageButton***

```
<div>
    <a href="#" onClick={onClick}>
        {add ? <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148790.svg" style={{ height: '15px' }} /> : null }
        {subtract ? <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148791.svg" style={{ height: '15px' }} /> : null}
    </a>
</div>
```

and this is my actual css:

this is a little piece of a card and is main container has this css

```
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E4E4
}
```

down below we have the percentge ( the big blue number )

```
.percentage {
  display: flex;
  color: #33BBFF;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

How can i align the two buttons to the percentage number and have them 
 vertically spaceless ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex layout like this:

```
<Container
  style={{
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }}>
  <LeftContainer>
    <Percentage />
  </LeftContainer>
  <RightContainer
    style={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    }}>
    <Button type="inc" />
    <Button type="sub" />
  </RightContainer>
</Container>;
```